# Update Swift Language: Type 'NSCoder' has no member 'plain'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am just update xcode(10.0) after update I was update as well as swift language version(4.2) but middle in progress of update swift language give me some error. I am really confused how to solve this:

**Error:**

> **Type 'NSCoder' has no member 'plain'**

```
 var _followingChatControl: FollowingChat!
    var followingChatControl: FollowingChat {
        get {
            if _followingChatControl == nil {
                _followingChatControl = FollowingChat.init(coder: .plain)
            }
            return _followingChatControl
        }
        set {
            _followingChatControl = newValue
        }
    }
```

**Error Screen Shot:**

[image: Screen Shot]

**FollowingChat Class Code:**

```
import UIKit

class FollowingChat: AbstractTableListControl{

    var listDataFollowing: [Following]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override var cellClass: AbstractTableCell.Type {
        return ScreenChatCell.self
    }

    override var isNibUsed: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func refresh() {
        super.refresh()
    }
```

**FollowingChat Class Screen Shot:**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without knowing what `FollowingChat` is and what initializers it has.

Comment: Pretty *objective-c-ishly* smelling code. In Swift the line `lazy var followingChatControl = FollowingChat(coder: .plain)` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @MartinR Please check

Comment: I still cannot see a `init(coder:)` initializer in your code ...

Comment: _followingChatControl = FollowingChat.init(coder: .plain) see this line

Comment: @MartinR it seems in `init(coder:)` the type is `NSCoder`. I looked in the documentation of NSCoder and there is no member ".plain"

Comment: after update the xcode as well swift version then show me error Type 'NSCoder' has no member 'plain'

Comment: @Dhiman Did you already look in the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoder) of NSCoder? There isnt a member plain. But it worked before you updated? Can you explain what .plain does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert the **required Initializer** to your `FollowingChat` class:

```
import UIKit

class FollowingChat: AbstractTableListControl{

var listDataFollowing: [Following]?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

override var cellClass: AbstractTableCell.Type {
    return ScreenChatCell.self
}

override var isNibUsed: Bool {
    return true
}

override func refresh() {
    super.refresh()
}
```

After you have done this, you can easily create a `FollowingChat` object:

```
var _followingChatControl: FollowingChat!
    var followingChatControl: FollowingChat {
        get {
            if _followingChatControl == nil {
                _followingChatControl = FollowingChat()
            }
            return _followingChatControl
        }
        set {
            _followingChatControl = newValue
        }
    }
```

The problem seems to be the `AbstractTableListControl` class where you inherit from. It needs that initializer to work. Just look what inititalizer are required in this class too. When the `AbstractTableListControl` class has for example a blank `init` function then you can add this to your `FollowingChat` class:

```
override init() {
 super.init()
 //your code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using another init in class.

```
init(dict : NSDictionary) {

}

And use it as below.


let _followingChatControl = FollowingChat.init(dict: [:])
```

[:] -> Object type goes here, I've used NSDictionary in example.